# MySql split table on insert

Tags: mysql, split

I am new so please go easy on me :)

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `send_sms` (
    `sql_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `momt` ENUM('MO','MT') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sender` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `receiver` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `udhdata` BLOB NULL,
    `msgdata` TEXT NULL,
    `time` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `smsc_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `service` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `account` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sms_type` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mclass` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mwi` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `coding` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `compress` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `validity` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deferred` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dlr_mask` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dlr_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pid` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `alt_dcs` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rpi` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `charset` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `boxc_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `binfo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `meta_data` TEXT NULL,
    `priority` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `foreign_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sql_id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I have two different applications talking to each other via these tables.

I would like to count the inserted rows (only 3 in below example, but could be 1000s at a time) and separate then into 3 other existing tables (same format)

So for Example:

```
INSERT INTO send_sms
( momt, sender, receiver, msgdata, sms_type, dlr_mask, dlr_url ) 
VALUES ( 'MT','1234', '447XXXXXXXX', 'Hello world4', 2, 27, 'test1' ),
( 'MT','Sender', '447XXXXXXXY', 'Hello world4', 2, 27, 'test2' ),
( 'MT','Sender', '447XXXXXXXY', 'Hello world4', 2, 27, 'test3' );
```

send_sms1 (would have test1)
send_sms2 (would have test2)
send_sms3 (would have test3)

Would need to be able to support if its not multiples of 3 example if its 10,000 rows send_sms1, send_sms2 should get 3,333 and send_sms3 should get 3,334 (doesn't matter which order). As this is a live system the table needs to be accessed at the same time (so during the move the table must be writable for other insert commands

I have tried things like like

```
INSERT INTO send_sms2(SELECT * FROM send_sms WHERE sql_id >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM send_sms_dump)/2);
```

- the above was just a test to split data- this worked however there isn't any delete so the data wasn't moved. Just 50K copied from the table to the other table

Please point me in the right direction so I can do some more research :)

Update thank you Rick James for the solution.

I am now trying to create an update trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER INSERT ON send_sms_dump
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Statement one
    INSERT INTO send_sms_dump2
    SELECT * FROM send_sms_dump
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 0;
    -- Statement two
    INSERT INTO send_sms_dump3
    SELECT * FROM send_sms_dump
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 1;
    -- More UPDATE statements
    INSERT INTO send_sms_dump4
    SELECT * FROM send_sms_dump
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 2;
    -- More UPDATE statements
    DELETE FROM send_sms_dump;
END$$
```

I have the above the error is ... /* SQL Error (1442): Can't update table 'send_sms_dump' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. */ ...

I am guessing its because of the delete command, i didn't want to drop the table as the third party application will be writing again to that table - let me know if i should post a new question :)

thanks guys

Comment: No -- just insert the one row, not 1/3 of the table.  The Trigger is called for each _row_, in spite of what the `FOR EACH ROW` may imply.

Comment: Furthermore, you have the current row in `OLD` or `NEW`, so you should not touch the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `sql_id`, so you have the rows numbered 1,2,3, 4,5,6, ... (unless you are using a clustering or Multi-Master setup that sets `auto_increment_increment` to something other than 1).

So, load the data into a table, then copy thirds into the three desired tables, and finally `DROP` the initial table.

```
INSERT INTO table_1
    SELECT * FROM table_all
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 0;   -- 0 for table_1. 1 for table_2, 2 for table_3
```

If you are *adding* to tables1/2/3, and they have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can get unique ids by _skipping `sql_id` in the transfer:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (b,c,d,e)
    SELECT b,c,d,e FROM table_all
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 0;
```

This assumes the columns in `table_all` are

```
sql_id,b,c,d,e
```

And table_1/2/3 have another column that is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Brilliant that works thank you! - Please could you help me setup a trigger on insert?                              ///DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER After_Insert
AFTER INSERT ON send_sms_dump
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO send_sms_dump2
    SELECT * FROM send_sms_dump
             WHERE sql_id % 3 = 0;
END $$
DELIMITER ;///

Comment: @mcgster - No.  A Trigger is invoked once for each _row_ inserted, not once for the entire `INSERT`.  (The "FOR EACH ROW" is confusing.)

Comment: Thanks again Rick and sorry to bug you again... I think I am going to do things a little differently. As I can see that we will get duplicated sql_ids as well

The send_sms_dump will be cleared down on every move so it might have the same sql_id on the next insert and will cause problems when moving the rows

Can you let me know if this sounds like it might work?

Create another column on send_sms default value = no something like “imported”

Comment: Create an event to select imported = “no” on send_sms_dummy every 60 seconds and run the insert queuery to move the rows with selected columns (no sql_id or imported) to send_sms_dump2/3/4 and update the imported to “yes” and the. run delete where imported is “yes”?

Comment: Perhaps what I added to my Answer works better than `imported`?  Caveat:  If you need the original `sql_id` values, then my suggestion is flawed.